# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to run my application server and i keep getting the following error back

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null
```

am using postgres as my database and below is the content of my db config file

```
development: {
    database: 'app_dev',
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL_DEV',
    dialect: 'postgres',
  },
  test: {
    database: 'app_test',
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL_TEST',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    logging: false,
  }
```

here am using `Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.18.3, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.4]`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when running a Node app in Heroku.

This is what fixed it:

```
development: {
    url: 'DATABASE_URL',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: {
            require: true,
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. It was because I was passing undefined arguments.

Comment: This was my situation, I had to remove 'options' from my knexflie

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Postgres initial configuration, you might need to add the following details at your config: `username` & `password`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the wrong env variables implementation + missing keys in config were the reasons of the error:

1. Check the format of your config/env vars. For example Heroku string vars don't work with additional `" "`!
2. Also I had to add `username` and `password` keys to `sequelize.json` in addition to existing `use_env_variable: DATABASE_URL`.